# ConEmu with Git Bash delete key won't work

Tags: git, bash, git-bash, conemu

I am using ConEMU with Git Bash and all is working well except the delete key. When I press the delete key I get a ~ instead of the character being removed. The only way to delete is get in front of the character and press backspace.

I do no exhibit this problem using Powershell so I presume something else must be upsetting it.

I have searched the settings under Keys and Macros but cannot find anything to fix my problem.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/detail?id=1816#c1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this into your .bashrc. Works fine for me.

> export TERM=xterm

Comment: Thanks , now it works perfectly! Been driving me mad for months :)

Comment: Ok, while the backspace key works the "end" key now exhibits the same behaviour so this isn't the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to the git menu option in the git bash..

then to Terminal

there change the type to xterm...
and backspace will work after restarting the bash terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I edit the file Minttyrc - ONLY SELECTED

BoldAsFont=no
Font=Lucida Sans Typewriter
**Term=xterm**
Transparency=low
CursorBlinks=no
CursorType=block
OpaqueWhenFocused=yes
BackspaceSendsBS=no
CtrlAltIsAltGr=no
AltFnShortcuts=yes
CopyOnSelect=no
CopyAsRTF=no
ClicksPlaceCursor=yes
DeleteSendsDEL=no
CtrlShiftShortcuts=yes
ClicksTargetApp=no

Comment: add some details to your answer